# create a dictonary with for loop in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I just want to create a dictionary with the help of for loop
sample code :

```
var counter: Int = 1;
var pageCountDict = [String:Any]();
    for filterCount in counter..<6
    {
       if let count = "page_\(filterCount)_vtime" as? String
       {
          pageCountDict = [count: timeInterval_Int];
       }
    }
print(pageCountDict);
```

**This print command give me only last value of forloop**
I just want all the value of this variable **pageCountDict** in a dictonary

Comment: You are overriding each time `pageCountDict` while you should do `pageCountDict[count] = timeInterval_Int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each loop, you are replacing the dictionary with one that contains only one element. What you want to do is this :

```
pageCountDict[count] = timeInterval_Int
```

Also, you shouldn't need the `as? String` part. This should be sufficient :

```
for filterCount in counter..<6
{
    pageCountDict[count] = "page_\(filterCount)_vtime"
}
```

Comment: awesome Dude Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The way to assign to a dictionary is first use the [subscript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/1641358-subscript) and assign the value to it:

```
pageCountDict[YourKey] = YourValue
```

Also, you can see many examples and explanations in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary) regarding dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

`var pageCountDict = [String:Any]()`

You can add values to this dictionary by merging previous contents and new data as follows...

```
let counter: Int = 1
var pageCountDict = [String:Any]()
for filterCount in counter..<6
{
   let value = 9
   let count = "page_\(filterCount)_vtime" //'if' is not needed as it is always true
   pageCountDict.merge([count: timeInterval_Int], uniquingKeysWith:{ (key, value) -> Any in
        //assign value for similar key
        timeInterval_Int
    })
}
print(pageCountDict)`
```